# Where is the missing comma or () in this Julia histogram?

Tags: julia, histogram

Downloaded Julia 15 min ago and thought I would play around.

I keep getting this error: syntax: missing comma or ) in argument list

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("CSV")
Pkg.add("DataFrames")
Pkg.add("Plots")

using CSV
using DataFrames
using Plots
 
iris = CSV.read("julia/iris.csv", normalizenames = true)

histogram(
    iris.sepal_length, 
    title = "This is my first Julia graph", 
    label = "size", 
    xlabel "X", 
    ylabel = "Y"
)
```

Have restarted kernel and written like matplot and seaborne, still getting error.

Also:

Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General`
Resolving package versions...
No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.5/Project.toml`
No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.5/Manifest.toml`
Resolving package versions...
No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.5/Project.toml`
No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.5/Manifest.toml`
Resolving package versions...
No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.5/Project.toml`
No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.5/Manifest.toml`

**Seems fine. Any ideas?
Thanks guys!**

#Edit: Also, this code:

```
p1 = scatter(iris.petal_length)
p2 = histogram(iris.petal_width)
p3 = histogram(iris.sepal_length)
p4 = scatter(iris.sepal_width)

plot = (p1, p2, p3, p4, layout = (2, 2), legend = false)

print(plot)
```

returns:
(p1 = Plot{Plots.GRBackend() n=1}, p2 = Plot{Plots.GRBackend() n=1}, p3 = Plot{Plots.GRBackend() n=1}, p4 = Plot{Plots.GRBackend() n=1}, layout = (2, 2), legend = false)

??????????

Comment: I'm voting to close because this is based on a simple typo. Also, those are actually two questions, which should be asked separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first error is:

```
xlabel "X",
```

which should be

```
xlabel = "X",
```

Your second error is that you are creating your final plot by putting `p1` to `p4` into a `NamedTuple`, rather than plotting them. You should be doing:

```
plot(p1, p2, p3, p4, layout = (2, 2), legend = false)
```

i.e. call the `plot` function with your subplots as arguments. Instead you are doing:

```
(p1, p2, p3, p4, layout = (2, 2), legend = false)
```

which is the Julia syntax for creating a `NamedTuple`, compare:

```
julia> (a = 1, b = "letters", c = false)
(a = 1, b = "letters", c = false)

julia> typeof(ans)
NamedTuple{(:a, :b, :c),Tuple{Int64,String,Bool}}
```